# Destroying accepts_nested_attributes_for association via unchecked checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, form-for, fields-for, accepts-nested-attributes

I'm creating checkboxes in a form that represent the notification methods a user is subscribed to, and that allow a user to subscribe to additional notification methods or unsubscribe from existing ones. Here's what the relationships look like:

```
class User
  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and...

```
class Subscription
  enum method: [:email, :txt]
  enum category: [:order_confirmation, :order_update]

  belongs_to :user

  validates :category, :method, presence: true
end
```

The form I'm working in uses `form_tag`.

If the user unchecks any of the checkboxes, I want the matching subscription to be deleted. I'm not sure if the best approach here is to use a `_destroy` attribute or to prevent all attributes for that checkbox from being sent to the server.

If it's the former, I guess I could create a hidden field for `_destroy`, but I have no idea how to conditionally set that hidden field to true depending on whether or not the checkbox is checked.

If it's the latter, I can't figure out how to NOT send my hidden fields along when a checkbox is unchecked. I need to include a `hidden_field` for the subscription's `id` so Rails doesn't create a new subscription if one already exists, as well as a `hidden_field` for the subscription's `category` so the correct type of subscription can be created.

Here's what the checkboxes I've created look like. Right now, I'm just creating checkboxes for the `order_update` notification type:

```
<% [{ label: "Email", value: "email" }, { label: "Text message", value: "txt" }].each_with_index do |options, index| %>
  <% existing_subscription = current_user.subscriptions.order_update.where(method: options[:value]) %>
  <%= fields_for "user[subscriptions_attributes][]", existing_subscription.first_or_initialize, index: index do |t| %>
    <%= t.hidden_field :category, value: :order_update %>
    <%= t.check_box :method, { checked: existing_subscription.any?, include_hidden: false }, options[:value] %>
    <%= t.label :method, options[:label] %>
    <%= t.hidden_field :id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If I'm currently subscribed to both email and text notifications, and then I uncheck the box for text, this is what I get in my params:

```
"subscriptions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"category"=>"order_update", "id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"category"=>"order_update", "method"=>"email", "id"=>"2"}}
```